Lawnmower Chipped Off Sewage Cleanout Lid — Best Replacement and Installation Process?
While mowing my lawn, the blades of my lawnmower accidentally struck and chipped off the sewage cleanout lid in my yard. The lid is marked with 'CO Josam.' The impact resulted in a clean break, leaving the cleanout exposed. I'm unsure of the best approach to replace the lid and ensure it’s securely installed to avoid future damage.

Should I replace the lid with a similar Josam product, or is there a better alternative for a high-traffic lawn area?
What is the recommended method for installing a new lid to prevent it from being damaged by lawn equipment in the future?

I've attached photos of the damage for reference.




If the pipe is not damaged, then replacing with the same size is okay.  Placing a couple of orange flags/sticks/cone should help to not hit it it again.

Looks like you sheared off the bolt head too?

@Huesmann Yes... best way to replace this as well?

@TomChen did you shear off all 3 bolts?

@Huesmann Yes, that's correct—or more precisely, one screw is completely sheared off, and the other two have the entire bracket sheared off. Is there any chance I can use a non-matching PVC lid to cover it?

It looks like the stack is cast iron, with the three bolt holes.  You can probably use a generic lid, but you will either need to drill out the sheared bolts, or find some other solution for keeping the lid in place.  What is the diameter of the lid?

Sorry for my delay @Huesmann. The lid's diameter is 5 inches. Besides drilling out the sheared bolts, what's the best way to keep a new lid in place?

If the existing lid is composite, perhaps replacing it with brass or cast iron would be sufficient weight to keep it in place.  Otherwise, perhaps you could get someone to weld some nuts to the ID of the cleanout bell, and bolt into those.

This doesn't appear to be the actual sanitary sewer cleanout, but rather an access housing that would cover the cleanout plug. Looking at Josam's web site it seems this product would normally be used in a concreted area to achieve a smooth, finished surface while maintaining the actual cleanout accessible.
The standing water within inches of grade level and the appearance that the cover was not not water-tight nor sewer-gas-tight are two things that give me this impression.
In my area we don't leave lawn-area sanitary sewer cleanouts exposed. They usually get trimmed and capped a few inches below grade, covered with soil, and the lawn runs right over the top.
If you like keeping the cleanout location visible, I'd replace it with another product just like the one that broke. I'd consider re-setting its elevation just a little lower to be out of harm's way, though.
